# Form calculations skip previous

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm working on a calculation script and it works perfect in all versions of FX but in other browsers any total values that were already filled in are lost after submitting if any required fields were left blank.

On this [form](http://www.idhsgb.com/iForms-test/breed/breedtest.php)  ,if you select a **Membership status** near the top and then go down to **Summary of entries** and fill in two values the totals to the right and the grand total at the bottom(above "Are you human") calculates correctly.

If you submit the form the validation kicks in and if you fill in another value the grand total only reflects that value and not the previous two which are still there.

I'm stumped since it works great in FX. I've looked for some kind of a reason for a week but this cross browser stuff is tricky. Thanks for any input.

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        var jQ = $.noConflict(true);

        // version 7
        jQ( document ).ready(function() {

//***  Member calculations
jQ('input[name="Class1-3Total"]').prop('readonly', true);

jQ('select[name="member_status"]').on('click', function() {
      if(jQ(this).val() == "FULL MEMBER"){
       // jQ('#docContainer #item303').css("display","none");//this hides the member stable days
      // jQ('#docContainer item298').css("display","none");//this hides the breedshow_grandtotal
       }
   });

jQ('input[name="quantity_class1-3"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
     var Class1_3Total = jQ(this).val() * 12;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "FULL MEMBER"){

        jQ('input[name="Class1-3Total"]').val(Class1_3Total);
        jQ('input[name="Class1-3Total"]').addClass( "sum" );


   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
            jQ('input[name="Class1-3Total"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="Class1-3Total"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_total();
 });

 jQ('input[name="class4_total"]').prop('readonly', true);
jQ('input[name="quantity_class4"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var class4_total = jQ(this).val() * 12;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "FULL MEMBER"){

        jQ('input[name="class4_total"]').val(class4_total);
        jQ('input[name="class4_total"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
            jQ('input[name="class4_total"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="class4_total"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_total();
});

    jQ('input[name="class19_total"]').prop('readonly', true);
    jQ('input[name="quantity_class19"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
    if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var class19_total = jQ(this).val() * 20;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "FULL MEMBER"){

        jQ('input[name="class19_total"]').val(class19_total);
        jQ('input[name="class19_total"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
            jQ('input[name="class19_total"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="class19_total"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_total();
});

       jQ('input[name="moorbennhall_total"]').prop('readonly', true);
        jQ('input[name="quantity_moorbennhall"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
        if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var moorbennhall_total = jQ(this).val() * 16;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "FULL MEMBER"){

        jQ('input[name="moorbennhall_total"]').val(moorbennhall_total);
        jQ('input[name="moorbennhall_total"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
            jQ('input[name="moorbennhall_total"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="moorbennhall_total"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_total();
});

       jQ('input[name="lakenview_total"]').prop('readonly', true);
        jQ('input[name="lakenview_quantity"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
        if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var lakenview_total = jQ(this).val() * 16;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "FULL MEMBER"){

        jQ('input[name="lakenview_total"]').val(lakenview_total);
        jQ('input[name="lakenview_total"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
            jQ('input[name="lakenview_total"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="lakenview_total"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_total();
});

       jQ('input[name="foalclasses_total"]').prop('readonly', true);
        jQ('input[name="quantity_foals"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
        if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var foalclasses_total = jQ(this).val() * 8;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "FULL MEMBER"){

        jQ('input[name="foalclasses_total"]').val(foalclasses_total);
        jQ('input[name="foalclasses_total"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
            jQ('input[name="foalclasses_total"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="foalclasses_total"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_total();
}); 

        jQ('input[name="total_allothers"]').prop('readonly', true);
        jQ('input[name="quantity_allothers"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
        if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var total_allothers = jQ(this).val() * 16;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "FULL MEMBER"){

        jQ('input[name="total_allothers"]').val(total_allothers);
        jQ('input[name="total_allothers"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
            jQ('input[name="total_allothers"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="total_allothers"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_total();
}); 

       jQ('input[name="firstaid_total"]').prop('readonly', true);
        jQ('input[name="firstaid_quantity"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
        if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var firstaid_total = jQ(this).val() * 5;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "FULL MEMBER"){

        jQ('input[name="firstaid_total"]').val(firstaid_total);
        jQ('input[name="firstaid_total"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
            jQ('input[name="firstaid_total"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="firstaid_total"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_total();
});
        jQ('input[name="catalogues_total"]').prop('readonly', true);
        jQ('input[name="quantity_catalogues"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
        if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var catalogues_total = jQ(this).val() * 4;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "FULL MEMBER"){

        jQ('input[name="catalogues_total"]').val(catalogues_total);
        jQ('input[name="catalogues_total"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
            jQ('input[name="catalogues_total"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="catalogues_total"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_total();
});

//*******  Stable cost for members
        jQ('input[name="stables_days_total"]').prop('readonly', true);
    jQ('input[name="stables_days_required[]"],select[name="stable_reqd"]').on('change', function() {
           if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "FULL MEMBER"){

           var values = new Array();
         jQ.each(jQ('input[name="stables_days_required[]"]:checked'), function() {
           values.push(jQ(this).val());

              if(values.length == 1){
                 var stabledays = 50;
              }else if(values.length == 2){
                 var stabledays = 80;
              }else if(values.length == 3){
                 var stabledays = 100;
              }


                if(stabledays > 0){
                jQ('input[name="days_stable"]').val(stabledays);
                }else{jQ('input[name="days_stable"]').val("");}


          if(jQ('select[name="stable_reqd"]').val() != "Please choose" && jQ('select[name="stable_reqd"]').val() == "ONE"){ 
                 var stable_reqd = 1;
             }else if(jQ('select[name="stable_reqd"]').val() != "Please choose" && jQ('select[name="stable_reqd"]').val() == "TWO"){
                 var stable_reqd = 2;
             }
              jQ('input[name="stables_days_total"]').val((stabledays*stable_reqd));
              if((stabledays*stable_reqd) > 0){
              jQ('input[name="stables_days_total"]').addClass( "sum" );

            }else{ jQ('input[name="stables_days_total"]').removeClass( "sum" );}
        });
        }
        calc_total();
  });
  //*** End of member stable calculations

 jQ('input[name="hogroast_total"]').prop('readonly', true);
jQ('input[name="quantity_hogroast"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var hogroast_total = jQ(this).val() * 16;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "FULL MEMBER"){

        jQ('input[name="hogroast_total"]').val(hogroast_total);
        jQ('input[name="hogroast_total"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
            jQ('input[name="hogroast_total"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="hogroast_total"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_total();
}); 

    jQ('input[name="electric_total"]').prop('readonly', true);
    jQ('input[name="quantity_hookup"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
    if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var electric_total = jQ(this).val() * 25;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "FULL MEMBER"){

        jQ('input[name="electric_total"]').val(electric_total);
        jQ('input[name="electric_total"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
            jQ('input[name="electric_total"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="electric_total"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_total();
});

jQ('input[name="voluntary_donation"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){

  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "FULL MEMBER"){
        jQ('input[name="voluntary_donation"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
        jQ('input[name="voluntary_donation"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_total();
});
jQ('input[name="breed_totalamount"]').prop('readonly', true);
    function calc_total() {
      var sum_member = 0;
        jQ('.sum').each(function(){
        if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
         sum_member += parseFloat(this.value);
          jQ('input[name="breed_totalamount"]').val(sum_member);
          jQ('input[name="breedshow_grandtotal"]').val(sum_member);
          }


        });
        if(!sum_member){

           jQ('input[name="breed_totalamount"]').val("");
          jQ('input[name="breedshow_grandtotal"]').val("");
          }
    }

    // ******* end of member calculations

  //*** Non-member calculations


    jQ('select[name="member_status"]').on('click', function() {
      if(jQ(this).val() == "Associate member/Non-member"){
        //jQ('#docContainer #item332').css("display","none");//this hides the non-member stable days
       // jQ('#docContainer item298').css("display","none");//this hides the breedshow_grandtotal
       }
   });
   jQ('input[name="Class1-3_none_T"]').prop('readonly', true);
jQ('input[name="quantity_class1-3_none"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
     var Class1_3_none_T = jQ(this).val() * 17;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "Associate member/Non-member"){

        jQ('input[name="Class1-3_none_T"]').val(Class1_3_none_T);
        jQ('input[name="Class1-3_none_T"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
        jQ('input[name="Class1-3_none_T"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="Class1-3_none_T"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_non_member_total();
 });

 jQ('input[name="Class4-4_none_T"]').prop('readonly', true);
jQ('input[name="quantity_class4_none"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var Class4_4_none_T = jQ(this).val() * 17;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "Associate member/Non-member"){

        jQ('input[name="Class4-4_none_T"]').val(Class4_4_none_T);
        jQ('input[name="Class4-4_none_T"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
        jQ('input[name="Class4-4_none_T"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="Class4-4_none_T"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_non_member_total();
});

     jQ('input[name="class19_none_T"]').prop('readonly', true);
    jQ('input[name="quantity_class19_none"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
    if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var class19_none_T = jQ(this).val() * 35;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "Associate member/Non-member"){

        jQ('input[name="class19_none_T"]').val(class19_none_T);
        jQ('input[name="class19_none_T"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
        jQ('input[name="class19_none_T"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="class19_none_T"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_non_member_total();
});


         jQ('input[name="lakenview_none_t"]').prop('readonly', true);
        jQ('input[name="lakenview_quantity_none"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
        if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var lakenview_none_t = jQ(this).val() * 24;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "Associate member/Non-member"){

        jQ('input[name="lakenview_none_t"]').val(lakenview_none_t);
        jQ('input[name="lakenview_none_t"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
        jQ('input[name="lakenview_none_t"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="lakenview_none_t"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_non_member_total();
});

       jQ('input[name="foalclasses_none_t"]').prop('readonly', true);
        jQ('input[name="quantity_foals_none"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
        if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var foalclasses_none_t = jQ(this).val() * 12;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "Associate member/Non-member"){

        jQ('input[name="foalclasses_none_t"]').val(foalclasses_none_t);
        jQ('input[name="foalclasses_none_t"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
        jQ('input[name="foalclasses_none_t"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="foalclasses_none_t"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_non_member_total();
}); 

       jQ('input[name="allothers_none_t"]').prop('readonly', true);
        jQ('input[name="quantity_allothers_none"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
        if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var allothers_none_t = jQ(this).val() * 24;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "Associate member/Non-member"){

        jQ('input[name="allothers_none_t"]').val(allothers_none_t);
        jQ('input[name="allothers_none_t"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
        jQ('input[name="allothers_none_t"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="allothers_none_t"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_non_member_total();
}); 

       jQ('input[name="firstaid_none_t"]').prop('readonly', true);
        jQ('input[name="firstaid_quantity_none"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
        if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var firstaid_none_t = jQ(this).val() * 5;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "Associate member/Non-member"){

        jQ('input[name="firstaid_none_t"]').val(firstaid_none_t);
        jQ('input[name="firstaid_none_t"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
        jQ('input[name="firstaid_none_t"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="firstaid_none_t"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_non_member_total();
});

        jQ('input[name="catalogues_total_none"]').prop('readonly', true);
        jQ('input[name="quantity_catalogues_none"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
        if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var catalogues_total_none = jQ(this).val() * 4;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "Associate member/Non-member"){

        jQ('input[name="catalogues_total_none"]').val(catalogues_total_none);
        jQ('input[name="catalogues_total_none"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
        jQ('input[name="catalogues_total_none"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="catalogues_total_none"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_non_member_total();
});

//*******  Stable cost for non members
        jQ('input[name="stables_days_none_t"]').prop('readonly', true);
    jQ('input[name="stables_days_required_none[]"],select[name="stable_reqd_none"]').on('change', function() {
           if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "Associate member/Non-member"){

           var values = new Array();
         jQ.each(jQ('input[name="stables_days_required_none[]"]:checked'), function() {
           values.push(jQ(this).val());

              if(values.length == 0){
                 var stabledays = "";
              }else if(values.length == 1){
                 var stabledays = 70;
              }else if(values.length == 2){
                 var stabledays = 100;
              }else if(values.length == 3){
                 var stabledays = 120;
              }


                if(stabledays > 0){
                jQ('input[name="days_stable_none"]').val(stabledays);
                }else{jQ('input[name="days_stable_none"]').val("");}


          if(jQ('select[name="stable_reqd_none"]').val() != "Please choose" && jQ('select[name="stable_reqd_none"]').val() == "ONE"){ 
                 var stable_reqd = 1;
             }else if(jQ('select[name="stable_reqd_none"]').val() != "Please choose" && jQ('select[name="stable_reqd_none"]').val() == "TWO"){
                 var stable_reqd = 2;
             }
              jQ('input[name="stables_days_none_t"]').val((stabledays*stable_reqd));
              if((stabledays*stable_reqd) > 0){
              jQ('input[name="stables_days_none_t"]').addClass( "sum" );

            }else{ jQ('input[name="stables_days_none_t"]').removeClass( "sum" );}
        });
        }
        calc_non_member_total();

  });

//*** End of non_member stable calculations

jQ('input[name="hogroast_none_t"]').prop('readonly', true);
jQ('input[name="quantity_hogroast_none"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var hogroast_none_t = jQ(this).val() * 16;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "Associate member/Non-member"){

        jQ('input[name="hogroast_none_t"]').val(hogroast_none_t);
        jQ('input[name="hogroast_none_t"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
        jQ('input[name="hogroast_none_t"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="hogroast_none_t"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_non_member_total();
});     


    jQ('input[name="quantity_hookup"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
    if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
       var electric_total = jQ(this).val() * 25;
  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "Associate member/Non-member"){

        jQ('input[name="electric_total"]').val(electric_total);
        jQ('input[name="electric_total"]').addClass( "sum" );


   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
        jQ('input[name="electric_total"]').val("");
        jQ('input[name="electric_total"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_non_member_total();
});

jQ('input[name="voluntary_donation"]').on('keydown keyup', function() {
if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){

  if(jQ('select[name="member_status"]').val() == "Associate member/Non-member"){
        jQ('input[name="voluntary_donation"]').addClass( "sum" );

   }
   }else if(!jQ(this).val()){
        jQ('input[name="voluntary_donation"]').removeClass( "sum" );

   }
   calc_non_member_total();
});

    function calc_non_member_total() {
      var sum_non_member = 0;
        jQ('.sum').each(function(){
        if(jQ.isNumeric(this.value)){
         sum_non_member += parseFloat(this.value);
          jQ('input[name="breed_totalamount"]').val(sum_non_member);
          jQ('input[name="breedshow_grandtotal"]').val(sum_non_member);
          }
        });
        if(!sum_non_member){

           jQ('input[name="breed_totalamount"]').val("");
          jQ('input[name="breedshow_grandtotal"]').val("");
          }
    }



});</script>
```

Comment: How can we possibly know what's wrong? You didn't provide any piece of code. It's like saying "My car har a problem" and expecting the miracle answer from the mechanic. Besides, what is FX?

Comment: FX= Firefox. It always works in every version but Chrome for example loses those previous values and calculates on anything added after the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting the above script to work in all browsers after doing some more testing and finding out that the validation script that was being provided by another source was the ultimate issue that was tripping up Chrome. We made some tweaks to that to reduce the number of errors it would show to one and changed the position of my calculation script in the head of the page in relation to the other provided scripts. For others that have browser compatibility issues keep digging and trying different things to eliminate and or pinpoint where the issue is coming from.